# Getting comboBox1.SelectedValue

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switchItem();
    }
private void switchItem()
        {
            var content = richTextBox1;
            switch (comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString())
            {
                case "Fruit":
                    content.Text = "Apple";
                    break;
                default:
                    content.Rtf = "Not Selected";
                    break;
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the `SelectedValue` of comboBox1 and this `object reference not set to an instance of an object` error showed up. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for `SelectedItem` rather than `SelectedValue`

The error `object reference not set to an instance of an object` means that `SelectedValue` is `null`